# JQuery-AJAX form submits but reloads page, changes url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm creating a Laravel application and am trying to get a form to submit without a page reload using AJAX. I feel like I am getting really close, but I am just missing something.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="new_stat" id="new_stat" role="form" >
```

My submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="addStatButton" />
```

Aaaand my Controller Method (ala Laravel):

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'stat' => 'required',
      'game_id' => 'required',
      'player_id' => 'required',
      'period' => 'required',
      'video_timestamp' => 'required',
    ]);

    $statToAdd = Stat_Meta::where('stat_abr', $request->input('stat'))->first()->id;

    $stat = new Stat;
    $stat->stat = $statToAdd;
    $stat->game_id = $request->input('game_id');
    $stat->player_id = $request->input('player_id');
    $stat->period = $request->input('period');
    $stat->video_timestamp = $request->input('video_timestamp');

    $stat->save();

    //I got rid of this thinking it would help stop the page reload. It didn't.
    //return redirect('/take-stats/1');
}
```

I tried this JS, but when I submitted the form, it registered the stuff to the database (yay!), but it reloaded the page and added parameters to the URL:

```
$('input#addStatButton').click( function() {
      $.post( '{{action("StatController@store")}}', $('form#new_stat').serialize(), function(data) {

         },
         'json' // I expect a JSON response
      );
  });
```

Now, after that, I read several places that I might wanna use 'submit' instead of 'click' if I didn't want the page reload, so I tried this:

```
    $('form#new_stat').on('submit', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $.post( 'post-stat', $('form#new_stat').serialize(), function(data) {

       },
       'json' // I expect a JSON response
    );
});
```

When I do this with 'e.preventDefault();' commented out, the page reloads, the url gets the parameters, but no record is added to the db. When I don't comment it out, no url change, no page reload, no record added to the db.

I am a TOTAL JQuery noob, I really prefer vanilla js, but I know that it is necessary to make this happen. I am not sure if maybe Laravel is involved in making this not work, or what is happening, but that is in fact why I posted my question here lol

Comment: Try returning false at the end of your submit event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change to `type="button"` to prevent reload page

```
<input type="submit" id="addStatButton" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="addStatButton" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked, can't believe it. Is it possible now to reload the area on my page where that data is displayed using AJAX (no page reload)? I load that data in using my Laravel controller, so it might not be.

Comment: You can use AJAX to get data and append to your area on your page without reload page

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` type will cause a page reload when you submit.
You could change the type to `button` and use the `click` event itself.

Or other wise, use the `click` event on the `submit` type input and fire the e.preventDefault() at the start of the event-handler